# Vertical align middle won't vertical align middle when the div is a fixed height

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

See below:

```css
.fixed-height {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.fixed-height h1 {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: red;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-height">
  <h1>VERTICAL ALIGN ME</h1>
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

> The vertical-align CSS property sets vertical alignment of an inline,
> inline-block or table-cell box.

[Vertically Align a Header Tag with Fixed Height through CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695857/vertically-align-a-header-tag-with-fixed-height-through-css)

```css
/* 
This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695857/vertically-align-a-header-tag-with-fixed-height-through-css

but it doesnt work either, it cuts the div short and isn't in the middle

*/

.fixed-height {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-table
}

.fixed-height h1 {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: red;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-height">
  <h1>VERTICAL ALIGN ME</h1>
</div>
```

1. Why is the box getting cut short?
2. Why won't it go to the middle?

I know that I can just do:

```css
/* 
Flex Version
*/

.fixed-height {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.fixed-height h1 {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: red;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-height">
  <h1>VERTICAL ALIGN ME</h1>
</div>
```

Which is what I did to get this done.

But I want to know why vertical align doesn't work when it's an inline element or inline box like documentation says.

Comment: please read the [manual / MDN WebDocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) - `vertical-aling` can't be used to align block-level-elements such as a `<h1>`. Also it aligns within the line-height not the entire parent element.

Comment: you want to know *why* but you accepted an answer not explaining anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `line-height` setting that is identical to the height of the container. This will vertically center the `h1` without any further settings:

```css
.fixed-height {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.fixed-height h1 {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-height">
  <h1>VERTICAL ALIGN ME</h1>
</div>
```